# How to set and retrieve cookie in laravel 5.2

Tags: cookies, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2 and I have to create keep me logged in functionality. 
I have used below code to set cookie:

```
$response->withCookie(cookie('email', $request['email'], 60));
```

for this I have included below namespace:

```
use Cookie;
```

After setting cookie I printed response and get something like below:

```
Response {#1028
  +original: ""
  +exception: null
  +headers: ResponseHeaderBag {#1029
    #computedCacheControl: array:1 [
      "no-cache" => true
    ]
    #cookies: array:1 [
      "" => array:1 [
        "/" => array:1 [
          "email" => Cookie {#989
            #name: "email"
            #value: "abc@gmail.com"
            #domain: null
            #expire: 90012626276.0
            #path: "/"
            #secure: false
            #httpOnly: true
          }
        ]
      ]
    ]
```

But When I try retrieving this cookie using any of below code it returned *'null'*

```
$request->cookie('email');
```

OR

```
echo cookie::get('email');
```

Searching on web didn't helped much as I don't have much time therefore posted it over here.

Also It would be great if someone can explain that would it be fine if I use setcookie php function to set cookie?
My colleague asked me to use laravel specific functions. So I am trying to implement -->

```
 $response->withCookie(cookie('email', $request['email'], 60));
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you try to get the cookie in the same request or you send the cookie and in the next call you try to fetch it?

Comment: In next call. As I need cookie in various other actions.

Comment: Should I use some other way to set cookie @AndrejLudinovskov

Comment: Do you use https or http?

Comment: I am using http. 'use Illuminate\Http\Request'.

Comment: No, your urls use http or https like http://<domain> or https://<domain>? @Simer

Comment: My url starts with http.

Answer (score 0):

To set a cookie you should use the following code without calling cookie() function:

```
$response->withCookie('email', $request['email'], 60);
```

Comment: Thanks! How to retrieve this cookie in some other action?

Comment: According to https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#cookies $request->cookie('email'); should work now.

Comment: When I fetch $request in some other action it does not contain 'email' cookie. So where is this cookie setting up?

Comment: It provides empty value like this : Cookie {#1026 ▼
  #name: "email"
  #value: null
  #domain: null
  #expire: 0
  #path: "/"
  #secure: false
  #httpOnly: true
} in case I use dd() OR email=deleted; expires=Sun, 06-Sep-2015 10:12:52 GMT; path=/; httponly in case I use echo. How can I get cookie values?

Comment: You can try my last idea \Request::cookie('email');. If it doesn't work I don't really know. @Simer